# Rails - Dynamic cookie domains using Rack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, dns, cross-domain

I'm fairly new to Rails and Rack, but this guy had a seemingly straightforward write-up about using [Rack to implement dynamic session domain middleware](http://codetunes.com/2009/04/17/dynamic-cookie-domains-with-racks-middleware/). The code looks good to and I've implemented it here on my local machine, but I'm still not able to transcend top level domains on a single login.

Here's the middleware code:

```
class SetCookieDomain
  def initialize(app, default_domain)
    @app = app
    @default_domain = default_domain
  end

  def call(env)
    host = env["HTTP_HOST"].split(':').first
    env["rack.session.options"][:domain] = custom_domain?(host) ? ".#{host}" : "#{@default_domain}"
    @app.call(env)
  end

  def custom_domain?(host)
    domain = @default_domain.sub(/^\./, '')
    host !~ Regexp.new("#{domain}$", Regexp::IGNORECASE)
  end
end
```

And then in environment.db:

```
config.load_paths += %W(#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/middlewares)
```

Lastly in production.db (and development.db):

```
config.middleware.use "SetCookieDomain", ".example.org"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I'm running Rails 2.3.3 and Rack 1.0

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems getting this to work in development mode.  When I was trying with localhost, I couldn't get it to work.  However, by accessing it via a domain configured in /etc/hosts to point to localhost, for example computer.local, I was able to get it to work.